# how to run a selenium test in mocha?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, coffeescript, mocha.js

I have a mocha test like this:

```
selenium = require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build()

after (done)->
  driver.quit().then done

describe 'simple test', ->
  before (done) ->
    driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8016').then done

  it 'should pass this simple test', (done) ->
    done()
```

But when I run it, I've got errors:

```
>mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register

  simple test
    1) "before all" hook

  2) "after all" hook

  0 passing (4s)
  2 failing

  1) simple test "before all" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:170:19)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)


  2)  "after all" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:170:19)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Versions:

- Mocha 2.2.1
- Coffee-script 1.9.1
- selenium-webdriver 2.45.1

How can I write a simple test that can pass?

UPD: I've passed it, but making a new driver for every test:

```
selenium = require 'selenium-webdriver'

describe 'simple test', ->
  @timeout 10000
  beforeEach ->
    @driver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build()
  afterEach (done)->
    @driver.quit().then -> done()

  it 'should pass this simple test', (done) ->
    @driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8016').then ->
      console.log('done')
      done()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that works has a timeout of 10s. Your original code uses the 2s default timeout. You should increase the timeout in the original code.

You should be able to simplify your code by returning promises instead of using `done`.

```
after ()->
  driver.quit();
```

For the benefit of those who don't do CoffeeScript, the above translates to:

```
after(function() {
  return driver.quit();
});
```

Since `driver.quit()` returns a promise, Mocha will use this promise to figure when the `after` hook is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the /testing area like so:

```
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
```

Then...

```
test.describe(...)
    it(...)
```

Seems this wrapper is needed with Mocha.

Comment: It is not *needed*, just a convenience. The OP here uses `.then(done)` to tell Mocha that a test is done. I've pointed out in my answer that it can be reduced to just returning the promise to Mocha. In earlier versions, Mocha did not support promises: you had to call `done` to inform Mocha that the test was done. At that time, using `selenium-webdriver/testing` was saving quite a bit of boilerplate. However, with promise support, I don't see a *lot* of benefit to using `selenium-webdriver/testing` and in fact I find it confuses people who don't already use it.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I was having the hardest time trying to figure out promises. This blog helped: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/04/webdriverjs-and-promises.html